# Should I keep the structure of the API request body same in all cases?

Tags: design-patterns, api, api-design, http-request

I have Items and Im creating an API which validates different aspects of an Item. eg: whether it has a valid height, width or depth.
My request body looks like

```
{
   height_check: true,
   width_check: true,
   depth_check: true
 }
```

The response looks like

```
{
   height_check: {
                   valid: true, 
                   value: "132cm"
                 },
   width_check: {
                   valid: false, 
                   value: "13cm"
                 },
   depth_check: {
                   valid: true, 
                   value: "32cm"
                 }
}
```

My question is if the user only wants to check the height, should they be allowed to send

```
{ height_check: true}
```

or should i force them to send

```
{
       height_check: true,
       width_check: false,
       depth_check: false
     }
```

In both cases I only intend to respond with

```
{   height_check: {
                   valid: true, 
                   value: "132cm"
                 },
}
```

Whats the better approach ?

Comment: I am not sure on why you need the caller to be able to specify what to check. Why not just check everything, every time? The caller can ignore the parts of the response that they don't care about.

Comment: Perhaps each check is costly and some clients are allowed to be able to skip those checks if needed.

Comment: This is a pretty common pattern. Having the client specify what details they care about is exactly the idea behind GraphQL. In this toy example it won't make any real difference, but if the response was a big object tree, containing lots of data aggregated from multiple datasources, then there's lots of room for optimization in the cases where the client is just interest in a small subset of the result payload.

Comment: @Graham Yes, each check is costly and in my actual usecase there is 20 different checks. Thanks for your response

Comment: @Alexander Ive simplified my usecase for the purpose of asking here, but  the real response is a big object tree. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be reasonable to me as the caller of the API that by NOT passing in a '*check=true' value that it would be equivalent to passing it in as false. Therefore I would allow callers of the API to omit the *check=false commands. This also gives you the power to add additional checks later, without forcing callers of the API to immediately pass a false value for those.

Comment: This works well with boolean properties. The only thing I would add is to ensure this behavior is included in any API documentation. Sometimes a boolean property can be `true`, `false` or`null`, with each value potentially resulting in different application behavior.

Comment: @Graham thats a great point about adding additional checks later. didnt occur to me. Thanks!